# case in where clause in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to check condition based on a value

```
where 
    PageName = @PageName
    and mal.ProductType = @ProductType 
    and isnull(MA.frzind, 0) = 0 
    and isnull(MA.ShowOnWeb, '') = 1
    and case 
           when isnull(mat.ActivityTypeCode, '') = 'ENQ'
              then mar.RegionCode = @VersionCode   
        end
```

I am getting this error:

> Incorrect syntax near '='

If `ActivityTypeCode= 'ENQ'` only then I have to check for

```
mar.RegionCode = @VersionCode
```

and `if ActivityTypeCode <> 'ENQ'`, then I don't have to check anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicit `case` expressions are generally discouraged from `where` clauses.  I would go for simple boolean logic:

```
where PageName = @PageName and
      mal.ProductType=@ProductType and
      coalesce(MA.frzind, 0) = 0 and 
      coalesce(MA.ShowOnWeb, '') = 1 and
      (coalesce(mat.ActivityTypeCode, '') <> 'ENQ' or
       mar.RegionCode = @VersionCode
      )
```

Comment: You realise `COALESCE` is a `CASE` expression too, right Gordon? :) [COALESCE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017): *"The `COALESCE` expression is a syntactic shortcut for the `CASE `expression. That is, the code `COALESCE(expression1,...n)` is rewritten by the query optimizer as the following CASE expression..."*

Comment: In Gordon's defense, he did say _explicit_ `CASE` expressions are discouraged. `COALESCE` is an _implicit_ `CASE` expression. ;)

Answer (score 1):

This gets away from the use of any functions in the `WHERE`, which should maintain SARGability, but does make a small guess on the logic. In your `CASE` expression you don't have an `ELSE`, so what happens if that evaluates to FALSE?

```
WHERE PageName = @PageName --What is the table alias for PageName?
  AND mal.ProductType=@ProductType 
  AND (frzind = 0 OR frzind IS NULL)
  AND MA.ShowOnWeb = 1 --There is no need for the ISNULL here, it'll just ruin performance. NULL = 1 = FALSE
  AND ((mat.ActivityTypeCode = 'ENQ' AND mar.RegionCode = @VersionCode)
   OR  (mat.ActivityTypeCode = 'ENQ' OR mat.ActivityTypeCode IS NULL)) --This is assumed logic
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
where PageName=@PageName
and mal.ProductType=@ProductType 
and ISNULL(MA.frzind,0)=0 and isnull(MA.ShowOnWeb,'')=1
and
(  
   (
       isnull(mat.ActivityTypeCode,'') = 'ENQ'
       AND
       mar.RegionCode = @VersionCode
   )
   OR  isnull(mat.ActivityTypeCode,'') <>'ENQ'
)
```